# Using element object with jQuery method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just started using jQuery. Now I want to use an jQuery method with an element object.

```
var element = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
element.offset();
```

Of course this doesn't work because the variable element is not a jQuery selector, so the error message I get in Firebug is "element.offset is not a function".
Is there any general method I could use this element object with an jQuery selector?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can turn a normal DOM element into a jQuery selection by wrapping it in `$()`:

```
var element = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
$(element).offset();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap it into the jQuery constructor function, which returns a `jQuery object`.

```
jQuery(element).offset();
```

or shortcut method

```
$(element).offset();
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Comment: OK, fail for me. I just read all the things about selectors without taking a look at the really easy methods... Thank you!